# Why is my apache regex [a-f0-9] only matching numbers?

Tags: regex, apache

I wrote a regex in order to match such files on a 2.4.35 Apache server

- stylesheet-0-0-0-16.css
- stylesheet-5-a-d-17.css
- stylesheet-a-a-8-18.css
- stylesheet-f-f-f-19.css

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /stylesheet(.)([a-f0-9])(.)([a-f0-9])(.)([a-f0-9])(.)([0-9]+)(.*)\.css/">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31557600, public"
</If>
```

It only matches files where first capture is a number, not a letter :

- stylesheet-**0**-0-0-16.css (match :-)
- stylesheet-**5**-a-d-17.css (match :-)

Files with a letter as first capture are not matched :

- stylesheet-**a**-a-8-18.css (no match :-(
- stylesheet-**f**-f-f-19.css (no match :-(

I don't understand why letters are not matched despite [**a-f**0-9].

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using:

```
stylesheet(?:-\w+){4}\.css$
```

Or in the `<if>` expression:

```sh
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /stylesheet(?:-\w+){4}\.css$/">
   Header always set Cache-Control "max-age=31557600, public"
</If>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xrw2C2/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `stylesheet`: Match `stylesheet`
- `(?:-\w+){4}`: Match a group 4 times where each group contains a substring of `-` followed by 1+ word characters.
- `\.css`: Match `.css`
- `$`: End

Comment: No it does not work. Apache seems to behave differently from other regex engines...

Comment: I updated question with full .htaccess. Thx !

Comment: site is not online already
URLs could be 
https://www.example.com/css/stylesheet-0-0-0-16.css
https://www.example.com/css/stylesheet-f-f-f-19.css

Comment: Does `https://www.example.com/css/stylesheet-0-0-0-16.css` get you a `200`? Check my updated rule. On my local Apache I create a dummy css file on that path and I get back `Cache-Control: max-age=31557600, public` in reponse.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I would have liked to know why my regex mysteriously does not work. Nevermind, I will use a less restrictive rule.

Comment: Your regex didn't work because it is not correct due to missing quantifiers and dot in regex matches any character. I have provided you a demo link of regex101 where you can copy/paste your regex and play with it.

Comment: What quantifiers are missing ? My regex works on regex101 but doesn't work on Apache...

Comment: Test your regex with `/css/stylesheet-0-10-0-16.css`

Comment: Such an URL never happens. The three strings that are located between hyphens are always 1 character long.

Comment: ok even if there are single characters between `-` why use `.` to match a `-`?

Comment: because using - (hyphen) or \- (escaped hyphen) does not work !

Comment: That means you are getting something other than `-` in URL